# How can I update pivot fields on Manage step with AJAX with OctoberCMS?

Tags: ajax, octobercms, octobercms-backend

I try to be able to get from a server some values for pivot data after linking a related record to the main one.
Here's a step of entering pivot data and some of them should be generated (no problem to enter them manually, the problem is to make it through AJAX):

[image: Related data]

Here's an example of related fields.yaml

```
fields:
    pivot[sort]:
        label: Order
        type: number
        span: auto
    pivot[time_from_start_to_sight]:
        label: Time from start to the sight
        type: number
        span: auto
    pivot[add_route_time]:
        label: Add time
        type: number
        span: auto
    pivot[add_route_price]:
        label: Basic add. price
        type: number
        span: auto
    pivot[stay_time_default]:
        label: Default stay time
        type: number
        span: auto
    pivot[stay_time_min]:
        label: Min. stay time
        type: number
        span: auto
    pivot[stay_price]:
        label: Price per quarter of hour
        type: number
        span: auto
    _gmaps_sync:
        label: You may try to get data from Google Maps API
        type: gmapsroutesightsync
        commentAbove: Make sure you have entered Google Maps API key
```

As you can see I added a custom widget to be able to paint a button. 
I can even call an AJAX-handler of a widget and apply new values to the passed data saving them to DB inside the controller.

But I do not have the slightest idea how to push updated partial or update the partial with new values. Of course it's possible update every field by non-organized JS code - but I'm sure there's a smart way.

Please point to the best practices. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you need to update your partial form, push it from controller where you are updating all data and saving it.

I guess for pivot data form you already defined the partial which will be rendering "relations" so you can update that partial.

when you do ajax call using October's ajax framework you can use something like

> data-request-update="relation: '#Form-relationClassesManagePivotForm'

OR

if programmatically you are firing request you can do

```
$.request('onRefreshTime', {
    update: { relation: '#Form-relationClassesManagePivotForm' }
})
```

you can check api in detail here : https://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/update-partials

here my pivot relation name is **"classes"** so id is generated like this, but you can inspect element to get proper id it will be inside "modal-body".

now from controller you just need to push updated partial and it will be updated automatically.

```
function onRefreshTime()
{
    return [
        '#Form-relationClassesManagePivotForm' => $this->renderPartial('pivot_form')
        // or 'relation' => $this->renderPartial('pivot_form')
    ];
}
```

here its better to write this method on same controller you are rendering page as it will be already defined definitions for relation so relation widget is already build.

if any confusion please let me know in comments.

### UPDATE

you need to add this code inside controller where you updating fields

```
return ['#myform' => $this->asExtension('RelationController')->onRelationClickManageListPivot()];
```

and you need to add one partial its override from the relation manger.
**you can see i am adding custm id = 'id'=>"myform"**

> _relation_pivot_form.htm (copy from relation manager and paste in your controller folder)

```
<?php if ($relationManageId): ?>

    <?= Form::ajax('onRelationManagePivotUpdate', [
        'data' => ['_relation_field' => $relationField, 'manage_id' => $relationManageId],
        'data-popup-load-indicator' => true,
        'id'=>"myform"
    ]) ?>

        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="popup">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title"><?= e(trans('backend::lang.relation.related_data', ['name'=>trans($relationLabel)])) ?></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <?= $relationPivotWidget->render(['preview' => $this->readOnly]) ?>
            <button
                type="button"
                data-request="onPivotRefresh"
                class="btn btn-primary">
                Refresh Partial
            </button>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <?php if ($this->readOnly): ?>
                <button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-default"
                    data-dismiss="popup">
                    <?= e(trans('backend::lang.relation.close')) ?>
                </button>
            <?php else: ?>
                <button
                    type="submit"
                    class="btn btn-primary">
                    <?= e(trans('backend::lang.relation.update')) ?>
                </button>
                <button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-default"
                    data-dismiss="popup">
                    <?= e(trans('backend::lang.relation.cancel')) ?>
                </button>
            <?php endif ?>
        </div>

    <?= Form::close() ?>

<?php else: ?>

    <?= Form::ajax('onRelationManagePivotCreate', [
        'data' => ['_relation_field' => $relationField, 'foreign_id' => $foreignId],
        'data-popup-load-indicator' => true
    ]) ?>

        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="popup">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title"><?= e(trans('backend::lang.relation.related_data', ['name'=>trans($relationLabel)])) ?></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <?= $relationPivotWidget->render() ?>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button
                type="submit"
                class="btn btn-primary">
                <?= e(trans('backend::lang.relation.add')) ?>
            </button>
            <button
                type="button"
                class="btn btn-default"
                data-dismiss="popup">
                <?= e(trans('backend::lang.relation.cancel')) ?>
            </button>
        </div>

    <?= Form::close() ?>

<?php endif ?>
```

I think it should do your work. if its not working then i need your code ;)

Comment: Thank you to find a time to asnwer!
Unfortunately I do not realize what you mean when you say "pivot data form you already defined the partial which will be rendering "relations" so you can update that partial."
I do not define a partial for that: it's rendered by the RelationController behaviour. I can copy that view from system directory and rerender from controller ajax handler but data consistency is lost...

Comment: no means if you didnt add it then its not needed to copy it then its fine , relation behaviour is already added so, it will pick up that partial from system.

Comment: Ajax error says that renderPartial is not defined. Should I use makePartial instead? Btw when I use makePartial('pivot_form') ajax error is _The partial '_pivot_form.htm' is not found_

Comment: can you try this one  => $this->relationRender('<your relation field name>'),  it should work

Comment: Doesn't work). I think I miss something fundamental about the CMS so let it be rude js-walkaround. Thanks again)

Comment: hmm, i will try it by my self in my plugin tomorrow and i will update answer :)

Comment: I'm betting there's something like 
_$this->initForm($model);_
_$this->initRelation($model, 'models');_
in your handler, isn't it?)

Comment: thanks, it works. 
If you don't mind I'd like to ask: how do you work in handler? I mean: yes, we can refresh data but the context of the handler has neither main model nor the related one: all I can to do is the return statement to pass rendered data which are built in RelationController. I can not interfer in init step or pass any values. All I have are just pieces of POST data from the model. Do you have some examples of code? If you don't let it go. The way of widgets I impelented works normally, I think. Thank you.

Comment: The main 'pro' to use widget ajax handler is that on the handler I can acces all vars I need to prepare data: 
$this->model for main model and  $this->controller->vars['formModel'] for the related one.

Comment: hmm, I don't have any code examples, but you can checkout this code https://github.com/octobercms/october/blob/master/modules/backend/behaviors/RelationController.php and try to find the way you want from the its variables and methods etc